# Does the sum of two linear operators with real spectra have real spectrum?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $C=A+B$, where $A$ and $B$ are linear operators defined on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space with real spectra, but they are not necessarily self adjoint operators. Is it true that $C$ always have real spectrum? Any comment or reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't an operator automatically self-adjoint if its spectrum is real? (Modulo some regularity assumption, of course).

Comment: A and B can be mapped into self-adjoint operators through similarity transformations : a = S A S^{-1}, b = T B T^{-1}, where a, b are self-adjoint operators. The question is whether there exists an invertible operator U where U (A+B) U^{-1} is self-adjoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's already false in dimension 2.
$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 4 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array}\right)+\left( \begin{array}{cc} -3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array} \right) .$$

Comment: That's a really nice example.